# keyPressed inverted in 2D game [P5.js]

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm learning p5 js and try to make a simple 2d snake game, but when I press the up arrow on keyboard the rectangle (the snake still does not exists) moves down, when I press the down arrow, it moves up

```
function keyPressed() {

if (keyCode ===  UP_ARROW ) {
    s.dir(0,1);
}
else if (keyCode === DOWN_ARROW) {
    s.dir(0,-1);
}
else if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {

    s.dir(1,0);
}
else if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
    s.dir(-1,0);
}
}


function Snake() {

   this.x = 0;
   this.y = 0;

   this.xspeed=1;
   this.yspeed=0;

   this.dir= function(x,y) {
      this.xspeed=x;
      this.yspeed=y;
   }

   this.update= function() {
      this.x += this.xspeed;
      this.y += this.yspeed;
   }
}
```

with this works fine...

```
if (keyCode ===  UP_ARROW ) {
    s.dir(0,-1);
}
else if (keyCode === DOWN_ARROW) {
    s.dir(0,1);
}
```

I don't understand why to move up the rectangle i have to modify the y speed with negative value.. any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, in computing, the origin of a graphic is in the **top** left, as opposed to mathematics, where it is in the **bottom** left, as shown in the below drawing:

[image: Origins diagram]

Because of this, in computing, if you want to move something up an image, you need to subtract, hence:

```
if (keyCode ===  UP_ARROW ) { s.dir(0,-1); }
else if (keyCode === DOWN_ARROW) { s.dir(0,1); }
```

<sub>In reality these extend into the negative numbers rather than stopping at 0 but this should give you the idea.</sub>